# Attach zip file to new issue in pydev tracker

Tags: pydev

I was attempting to create a new issue in the Pydev issue tracker but I was unable to find a way to attach a `zip` file to the issue description. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you're expected to provide code as a project on github or as a gist and images on an imaging service (such as imgur).